# Seagate expansion drive 2TB not recognized on windows after mac

Tags: hard-drive

After i connected my seagate expansion drive to my macbook air, it opened normally as  far as  i remember

But now if i'm connecting it on windows 7, it shows that driver installation and the option for ejection, but it doesnt show it on my computer

So, has the mac made any changes on it?

Comment: Have you ever been able to use this disk on Windows?

Comment: Yes. Before I used it on my Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading the driver directly from the Seagate site before plugging it back into your windows computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the latest driver on your Win 7, then the connection should be ok.